# JavaFX executable Jar

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have finished my JavaFx application, I am using Netbeans 8.0. Everything is okay, I have set the main class and created the executable jar file for the project.
When I run each individual JFrame, I display my Jasper Reports Okay, but when I run the whole project, that is I right click on the project and select run, I cant display any report. I run into the following error:

```
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: Body event threw error
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.commons.digester.SetNestedPropertiesRule$AnyChildRule.body(SetNestedPropertiesRule.java:458)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.body(Rule.java:220)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1315)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigester.endElement(JRXmlDigester.java:199);
```

Does anyone know a way around this please?

Comment: I don't get the connection with Java-FX.  Is this app. using Swing or Java-FX components?

Comment: this is a JavaFX application, with some swing components such as JFrames and JPanels